# Points along one or more lines at a time, with rotation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, feature-class

I'm using ArcMap 10.3, and I have several lines, that I would like to add arrows along at a defined interval, with that lines rotation, so the arrows point correct way along the line.

When I use the construct point (while having a line marked) I can get points at a defined interval for one line at a time, but it does not rotate according to the line direction. The funny thing is, it pretty much shows a preview, when you use this tool, with exactly the type of points I want (maybe a different arrow type), question is, how do I get it as shown on the picture below?

So to sum up, I would like to add points (in the shape of arrows) along a line, with the arrows pointing in the line direction.

[image: What I want]

Tried what is suggested at:
[Unable to rotate Marker Line Symbols](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118994/unable-to-rotate-marker-line-symbols?rq=1)

However this gives the difference, that smaller lines will have perhaps 5 markers on a line of 100 meters, but a line of 10000 meters will also have 5, so the interval is not ~ close to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line shown below drawn using @Richard Fairhurst solution for [my question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112286/showing-directional-line-symbol-in-arcgis-for-desktop)

[image: Line symbology]

Alternatively use workflow below, to assign correct bearing to your points, called “chainage”.

```
arcpy.AddField_management("chainage","IDFIELD","LONG")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("chainage", "IDFIELD", "[FID]")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("chainage", "D:/Scratch/buffers.shp","5 Meters")
arcpy.Intersect_analysis("LINE #;buffers #", "D:/Scratch/directions.shp", "ALL")
```

Note that my line(s) layer called LINE. At this stage you can use “directions” with arrow-right symbol:

[image: Segments]

If you insist on points, calculate “directions” bearing:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("directions", Geometry_Properties="LINE_BEARING")
```

Transfer bearing to chainage points using common “IDFIELD” and apply rotation to point symbol:

[image: Symbol]
[image: Point Symbol]

Solution assumes you know how to place points at regular interval.

You might experiment with distance between points and buffer size and smoothed version of your line. In above example I placed points at 100m interval and used 5m buffer.