# Rotating point feature symbols by intersect polyline in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I would like to rotate point features symbols by angle of polyline that they overlap. Similar to cartographic line symbol, that can rotate to follow line angle:

[image]

I´m using basic license of **ArcGIS 10.1**. I´m not able to use [Points along one or more lines at a time](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214720/points-along-one-or-more-lines-at-a-time-with-rotation), with rotation solution. It was made for ArcGIS 10.3. I think that method arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management can be used from **ArcGIS 10.2.**

I followed this approach:

- Create buffer Find upper and lower intersection (buffer x line)
- Calculate angle
- Update point feature attribute with calculated angle
- Rotate point by attribute with calculated angle

Solution could by something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I have basic licence ArcGIS 10.1. I can´t use method arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management.

Solution found upon comment post by @FelixIP and upon solution found for question [Bearing between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058617/bearing-between-two-points) made by John Machin.

```
import arcpy
from math import degrees, atan2
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


#input layer
fcin_points = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #input point # feature layer
fcin_lines = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #input lines # feature layer

#temp layer
fctemp_buffer = "in_memory/buffers"
fctemp_direction = "in_memory/directions"

#field management
arcpy.AddField_management(fcin_points,"n_IDFIELD","LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(fcin_points,"ANGLE","DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fcin_points, "n_IDFIELD", "[FID]")

#buffer and intersection
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fcin_points, fctemp_buffer,"0.1 Meters")
arcpy.Intersect_analysis([fcin_lines,fctemp_buffer], fctemp_direction, "ALL")

#calculate angle
try:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fctemp_direction, ["SHAPE@","n_IDFIELD"]) as scur:
        for srow in scur:
            selectID = srow[1]
            PointsIDField = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fcin_points, "n_IDFIELD")
            WC = PointsIDField + " = " + str(selectID)
            geom = srow[0]
            firstX = geom.firstPoint.X
            firstY = geom.firstPoint.Y
            lastX = geom.lastPoint.X
            lastY = geom.lastPoint.Y
            angle = degrees(atan2(lastY - firstY, lastX - firstX))       
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcin_points,"ANGLE",WC) as ucur:
                for urow in ucur:
                    urow [0] = angle
                    ucur.updateRow(urow)
#Cleaning
    del scur
    del ucur

    arcpy.DeleteField_management(fcin_points, "n_IDFIELD")
    arcpy.Delete_management(fctemp_buffer)
    arcpy.Delete_management(fctemp_direction)

#how to rotate symbols
    arcpy.AddMessage("\n" + "Symbology -> Advanced -> Rotation -> ANGLE -> Arithmetric" + "\n")

except Exception:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    arcpy.AddError(e.args[0] + "\n" + "Does following layer contain M coordinate?" + "\n" + fcin_lines )
```

Solution:
[image: Solution]