# Deriving point rotation from line direction in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

This question is related to [Rotating point feature symbols by intersect polyline in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268131/rotating-point-feature-symbols-by-intersect-polyline-in-arcgis-desktop), but my problem differs slightly.

I have a layer with polygons (nearly all rectangular) and a second one with points. The points are set in the middle of one of the sides of each polygon. I need to represent the points as arrows pointing directly into the polygon. So far I use an attribute of the point layer for rotation and fill the rotation in manually, but I was wondering, if I could derive the rotation value from the direction of the polygon segment automatically?

I use QGIS 2.18.16 on a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Do they have common id fields which define point-polygon relationship?

Comment: Yes they have a common unique ID. The relationship is also defined spatially, since the point is set (snapped) on the polygon edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstood your requirement; this is what I had by a **Virtual Layer**.

[image]

This query is:

```
SELECT make_line(testpoint.geometry, st_centroid(testpolygon.geometry))
FROM testpoint
INNER JOIN testpolygon
ON testpoint.id = testpolygon.id
```

---

EDIT:

You needed `rotation value`, rather than the arrow ... my apologies.

```
SELECT degrees(st_azimuth(testpoint.geometry, (st_centroid(testpolygon.geometry)))) 
       AS deg, 
       make_line(testpoint.geometry, st_centroid(testpolygon.geometry)) 
       AS geometry
FROM testpoint
INNER JOIN testpolygon
ON testpoint.id = testpolygon.id
```

[image]

---

Edit 2: To combine the azimuth data with the point layer, a syntax like below can be used. If other attribute fields from point layer are needed, add them to the `SELECT`, too.

```
SELECT testpoint.*,
       degrees(st_azimuth(testpoint.geometry, (st_centroid(testpolygon.geometry)))) AS deg
FROM testpoint
INNER JOIN testpolygon
ON testpoint.id = testpolygon.id
```

For this time, please explicitly set the geometry type to Point, as the previous layer was automatically set to line.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. It works in a way, but as soon as I hand it more than one pair of point and polygon, the virtual layer produces only one point nevertheless. Perhaps I made a mistake.
Here is the Code I typed:
SELECT degrees(st_azimuth(point.geometry, (st_centroid(poly.geometry)))) 
       AS deg, 
       make_line(point.geometry, st_centroid(poly.geometry)) 
       AS geometry
FROM point
INNER JOIN poly
ON point.code_schn = poly.code_schn

Comment: @akra-kachi Your syntax looks good to me. Will you re-run the SQL after adding new pairs? Right-click the virtual layer ->> Edit virtual layer settings will call up the Virtual Layer window. Then click [OK] to re-run.

Comment: No, I gave it my layers with about 40 points/polygons. Solved this issue, however. I had the geometry type of the virtual layer set to point, but if I set it on automatic it works.

Now I am just wondering, how to transfer the data from the virtual layer into the attribute table of the original point layer.

Comment: @akra-kachi Glad to hear you have solved it. As to the latter part, I will add another syntax to combine the azimuth data to a point layer.

Comment: Works perfectly. In case anyone has (like me) problems copying the values from the deg-field into the original point layer attribute table see this tutorial http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/performing_table_joins.html and then copy the attributes from the new virtual_layer_deg column into the original column using the field calculator.